# Syntax for calling Firebase recyclerview query

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database

I'm creating a query to sort my firebase recyclerview by timestamp in a fragment.  I have a syntax question on how to call the query.

Here is a clip of the code I have. 
I'm unsure about how to write the line "query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(????)"

```
public void onStart(){
    super.onStart();

    FirebaseRecyclerOptions<Posts> options =
            new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<Posts>()
            .setQuery(usersRef, Posts.class)

            .build();

    Query query = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("postId").orderByChild("timestamp").limitToFirst(100);

    query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(????)

    FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Posts, viewPostsViewHolder> adapter =
            new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Posts, viewPostsViewHolder>(options) {
                @Override
                protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final viewPostsViewHolder holder, final int position, @NonNull Posts model) {

                    final String postId = getRef(position).getKey();

                    usersRef.child(postId).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onDataChange(@NonNull final DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                            Log.e("heredata","heredata"+dataSnapshot);

                            if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {
```

Thanks in advance to any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're trying to show the query results in the recycler view, you should pass that query into the builder's `setQuery(...)` call:

```
Query query = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("postId").orderByChild("timestamp").limitToFirst(100);

FirebaseRecyclerOptions<Posts> options =
        new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<Posts>()
                                   .setQuery(query, Posts.class)
                                   .build();
```